# System of equation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix made from the variable coefficient of the following system. Let $B$ be a $3 \times 1$ matrix made from the coefficients of the right hand side. Solve the system by computing $A^{-1}B$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
8x+8y-z & = &117\\
x+5y-9z & = &24\\
7x+y+z & = & 54
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What have you tied, or where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not even know where to start. I just learned how to multiply two by two matrices together. I somewhat know systems of equations. However, if I try this question it will be wrong. It is hard to learn the formatting for this website too. I try my best but it takes me a long time. Do you understand it ?

Comment: Look up MathJax on Google (or in the Your Answer box here, click the question mark on the upper right, and go to advanced help.

Comment: Or you can click edit on your question, to see what @Mnifldz did to set up your question; it is nice to learn by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First learn to multiply matrices of any compatible shape together:

If $A$ is $m\times k$ and $B$ is $k \times n$ then these can be multiplied in the order 
$AB = C$ and $C$ is $m\times n$.  So in your problem $A$ is going to be $3 \times 3$ and $b$ is $3\times 1$ and $AB$ is   $3\times 1$ and is the list of answers for $x,y,z$.

TO multiply matrices $AB$ , you find the sums of products, going across the rows of $A$ and the columns of $B$ -- that is why the number of columns of $A$ needs to match the number of rows of $B$.

For instance
$$\left(\matrix{1&2\\3&4 }\right) \left( \matrix{5\\6} \right) = \left(\matrix{1\cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 6 = 17\\3\cdot 5 + 4 \cdot 6 = 39}\right) =\left(\matrix{17\\39}\right)
$$

Then you can look up how to invert a matrix.  The best way for you is probably going to be Gaussian elimination. The matrix to start with is the coefficients in your equations:
$$
\left(\matrix{
8&8&-1\\1&5&-1\\7&1&1}
\right)
$$

ALthough shortcuts would be taken by experienced people, the easy way to see Gaussian elimination is that you are doing the same operatoins of adding a multiple of one row to another row, on the original matrix -- with the aim of reaching the identity matrix -- and on the identity matrix (which will end up being the inverse of the original.  (the operations can include dividing a whole row by some number).

For example:
$$
\left(\matrix{
8&8&-1\\1&5&-1\\7&1&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
15&9&0\\1&5&-1\\7&1&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
15&9&0\\8&6&0\\7&1&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
15&9&0\\\frac 43&1&0\\7&1&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
1&0&1\\0&\frac 16&\frac16\\0&0&1}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
15&9&0\\\frac 43&1&0\\\frac {17}{3}&0&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
1&0&1\\0&\frac 16&\frac16\\0&-\frac 16&\frac 56}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
3&0&0\\\frac 43&1&0\\\frac {17}{3}&0&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
1&-\frac 32&-\frac12\\0&\frac 16&\frac16\\0&-\frac 16&\frac 56}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
1&0&0\\\frac 43&1&0\\\frac {17}{3}&0&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
\frac13&-\frac 12&-\frac16\\0&\frac 16&\frac16\\0&-\frac 16&\frac 56}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\\frac {17}{3}&0&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
\frac13&-\frac 12&-\frac16\\-\frac49&\frac 56&-\frac1{18}\\0&-\frac 16&\frac 56}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
\right)\left(\matrix{
\frac13&-\frac 12&-\frac16\\-\frac49&\frac 56&-\frac1{18}\\-\frac{17}{9}&\frac 83&\frac {16}{9}}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(\matrix{
\frac13&-\frac 12&-\frac16\\-\frac49&\frac 56&-\frac1{18}\\-\frac{17}{9}&\frac 83&\frac {16}{9}}
\right)\left(\matrix{117\\24\\54} \right) = 
$$
and that last product gives you your answer.  I have not done the work for you because I havve left two errors in the sequence of steps -- but you can see how the inversion is done.

ANoother way to invert a 3 by 3 matrix involves determinants, it you have learned about them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a freebie.  The left sides of the equations above can be written in matrix notation by the following:

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
8 & 8 & -1 \\
1 & 5 & -9 \\
7 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; A\textbf{x}.
$$

$B$ is the column vector you get from right-hand sides of the equations above.  Lastly, to compute $A^{-1}$ you will need to perform Gaussian elimination to invert $A$.  Do these concepts make sense?